# Creating a control bound to a variable

Tags: .net, controls

Is it possible to create a textbox or other control that is bound to a variable or property? 
I want to have a control that will show the current value of a control and update the variable with a new value if the control changes.

Is there some control I could download that already has this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would DataBindings be what your looking for? Binds a control to a property :

```
myTextbox.databindings.add("text", classWithProperty, "propertyName")
```

That's how I did it in VB.NET, but i'm a bit rusty.

EDIT:

I believe you need to implement iNotifyPropertyChanged for the values to update:

```
Public Class YourClassWithProperty
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Then make a function :

```
Public Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal name As String)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(name))
End Sub
```

After, call the function in your property's "set" area :

Example :

```
Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        Return personName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        personName = value

        OnPropertyChanged("Name")
    End Set
End Property
```

Examples taken from msdn : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx

Comment: Thats nice. However, when the value is updated outside of the control, the control does not show the new value.

Comment: I think you have to implement INotifyPropertyChange to update it. Here it is on msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx 
Call it when in the property's set area.

Comment: I had to add the below line to the class with the property to get it to work. Otherwise, thanks!  `Public Event PropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged`

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple Textbox, add a event for example ´onLostFocus´ and update your variable there.

Comment: But can I somehow bind a variable to the control so I dont have to write that for every control?

Comment: take a look a this post  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/BlogDetail.aspx?BlogId=581 and let me know if it was useful please

Comment: or this if you are using winforms :) http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/09/16/binding-control-properties-to-business-object-properties.aspx